# Windows XP Home instalation stops after first reboot

Tags: windows-xp

I have a problem. I must instal Windows XP home edition but when. Problem is instalation stops after copying files and first reboot.

I have ASUS P5GC-MX motherboard and SATA drive.

I did format and even created partitions from start but i didnt work.

Any idea??

Comment: After the first boot you should choose boot from harddrive

Comment: What is your HDD showing in BIOS: AHCI, RAID or IDE/Compatibility?

Comment: Thx for answer. I dont know why but it did go to the next step. I did one more format in Windows 7 instaler (but i did like 3 times before) and it worked.

Comment: So, there is **no more question** since you've fixed it? In that case, you can either delete the question or we can close it.

Answer (score 1):

Check HDD mode in BIOS Setup, it must be IDE/Legacy. After first reboot set HDD as first boot device.